# ChoiceModelR - Hierarchical Bayes Multinomial Logit Model

Tags: r, bayesian, multinomial

I hope that some of you are a bit experienced with the R package `ChoiceModelR` by Sermas and Colias, to estimate a Hierarchical Bayes Multinomial Logit Model. Actually, I am quite a newbie on both R and Hierarchical Bayes. However, I tried to get some estimates by using the script provided by Sermas and Colias in the help file. I have a data set in the same structure as they use (ID, choice set, alternative, independent variables, and choice variable). I have four independent variables all of them binary coded as categorical variables, none of them restricted. I have eight choice sets with three alternatives within each set as well as one no-choice-option as fourth alternative. I tried the following script:

```
library (ChoiceModelR)
data <- read.delim("Z:/KLU/CSR/CBC/mp3_vio.txt")   
xcoding=c(0,0,0,0)  
mcmc = list(R = 10, use = 10)  
options = list(none=FALSE, save=TRUE, keep=1)  
attlevels=c(2,2,2,2)  
c1=matrix(c(0,0,0,0),2,2)  
c2=matrix(c(0,0,0,0),2,2)  
c3=matrix(c(0,0,0,0),2,2)  
c4=matrix(c(0,0,0,0),2,2)  
constraints = list(c1, c2, c3, c4)  
out = choicemodelr(data, xcoding, mcmc = mcmc, options = options, constraints = constraints)
```

and have got the following error message:

```
Error in 1:nalts[i] : result would be too long a vector
```

In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use `warnings()` to see the first 50). The mentioned warnings are of the following:

1. `In max(temp[temp[, 2] == j, 3]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`
2. `In max(temp[temp[, 2] == j, 3]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Actually, I have no idea what went wrong so far as I used the same data structure even I have more independent variables, more choice sets, and more alternatives within a choice set. I would be fantastic if anybody can shed some light into the darkness

Comment: I hope that your realize that without your data it will be difficult to know why it fails

Comment: Yea, I know but I hope that someone who allready have some experience with the package might see some missings or wrong parts in the code. If needed, I can upload my data too.

Comment: No need to upload your data but just create a reproductible example :  Some data + code to reproduce the same type of error you have. This more or less the rule here in Stackoverflow if you want people to help you. Now if there's no confidentiality issue, then you can try to load it

Comment: Thank you dickoa. Stupid question: how can I provid you with data? By a link (e.g. dropbox)? thx

Answer (score 3):

I know that this may not be helpful since you posted so long ago, but if it comes up again in the future, this could prove useful.

One of the most common reasons for this error (in my experience) has been that either the scenario variable or the alternative variable is not in ascending order within your data.

```
id    scenario    alt    x1   ...    y
1     1           1      4           1
1     1           2      1           0
1     3           1      4           2
1     3           2      5           0
2     1           4      3           1
2     1           5      1           0
2     2           1      4           2
2     2           2      3           0
```

This dataset will give you errors since the scenario and alternative variables must be ascending, and they must not skip any values.  Just to fully reiterate what I mean, the scenario and alt variables must be reordered as follows in order to work:

```
id    scenario    alt    x1   ...    y
1     1           1      4           1
1     1           2      1           0
1     2           1      4           2
1     2           2      5           0
2     1           1      3           1
2     1           2      1           0
2     2           1      4           2
2     2           2      3           0
```

I work with ChoiceModelR quite frequently, and this is what has caused these errors for me in the past.  If you have a github account, you can also post your data (or modified data) there if you end up wanting to have other users take a look.