# ChoiceModelR, none=TRUE, "Error in betadraw[good, ] = newbeta[good, ]"

Tags: r, bayesian, hierarchical, mlogit

I am using ChoiceModelR for hierarchical multinomial logit. I want to get estimates for the utility of the outside good (which follows a normal distribution). The outside good has no covariates like the inside goods - e.g. it cannot have a price or brand dummy - , so I set list(none=TRUE) and do not add this no-choice to the X data (as described in the documentation of ChoiceModelR) but only to the y (choice) data.

The iterations start normally, then at some point it stops and says

```
"Error in betadraw[good, ] = newbeta[good, ] :   NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments".
```

This likely happens because in row 388 of the function "choicemodelr", the "good" subscript is NA.

I looked at some questions about choicemodelr ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518092/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-choicemodelr-rhiermnlrwmixture-in-r),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522204/choicemodelr-hierarchical-bayes-multinomial-logit-model),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793592/choicemodelr-part-worths)), and also about NAs in subscript ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893023/nas-are-not-allowed-in-subscripted-assignments),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064044/nas-are-not-allowed-in-subscripted-assignments)), but my guess is that my problem is specific to this function in the sense that probably some inputs in the iteration just get so large/small such that "good" will turn to be NA.

Below is a very simple example. I generate data with 3 products with varying attributed. In half of the periods product 3 is not offered. The 2000 consumers have preferences - distributed normally - over 3 attributes (and a preference for the outside good). Logit error added to be consistent with the model. Outside good is indexed as product 4 (both when 3 and 2 products were in the choice set).

How could I avoid the NA error? Am I doing something wrong, or is it a general bug in the function?

I also searched for examples online setting the option none=TRUE, but I did not find any reproducible one. Perhaps this option is only the problematic thing as there is no problem recovering the true parameters if I set none=FALSE, and I do not let customers choose the outside option.

So the code which results in the NA bug is the following:

```
library("ChoiceModelR")
library("MASS")

set.seed(36)

# Set demand pars
beta_mu = c(-3,4,1)
beta_sigma = diag(c(1,1,1))
alfa_mu = 5  #outside good mean utility
alfa_sigma = 2  #outside good sd

# Three/two products, 3 vars (2 continuous,1 dummy)
threeprod <- list()
twoprod <- list()
purchase <- list()

for (t in 1:1000){
  threeprod[[t]] = cbind(rep(t,3),c(1,1,1),c(1,2,3),runif(3),runif(3),ceiling(runif(3,-0.5,0.5)))
  purchase[[t]] = which.max(rbind(threeprod[[t]][,c(4,5,6)]%*%mvrnorm(1,beta_mu,beta_sigma) + 
    matrix( -log(-log(runif(3))), 3, 1),rnorm(1,alfa_mu,alfa_sigma)) )
  threeprod[[t]] = cbind(threeprod[[t]],c(purchase[[t]],0,0))
}

for (t in 1001:2000){
  twoprod[[t]] = cbind(rep(t,2),c(1,1),c(1,2),runif(2),runif(2),ceiling(runif(2,-0.5,0.5)))
  purchase[[t]] = which.max(rbind(twoprod[[t]][,c(4,5,6)]%*%mvrnorm(1,beta_mu,beta_sigma) + 
    matrix( -log(-log(runif(2))), 2, 1),rnorm(1,alfa_mu,alfa_sigma)) )
  if (purchase[[t]] == 3) {purchase[[t]] <- 4}
  twoprod[[t]] = cbind(twoprod[[t]],c(purchase[[t]],0))
}

X <- rbind(do.call(rbind,threeprod),do.call(rbind,twoprod))

xcoding <- c(1,1,1)

mcmc = list(R = 5000, use = 2000)
options = list(none=TRUE, save=TRUE, keep=5)

out = choicemodelr(X, xcoding, mcmc = mcmc,options = options)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to sort them by ID,Set,Alt .. that solved the error (the same you got)The questions have to sorted by Respondent ID, The set number (Questions) and Alternatives in a given question.